# SVG - Create outer stroke of different merged paths

Tags: svg

I have an SVG file which represents a map using different paths.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB5zo.jpg

These paths represents different areas; I need to make bold the outer stroke that these paths create, as represented in this picture (note that there are 2 SVGs in a single file).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCoAp.jpg

Is it possible to achieve thisin a simple way?

Thanks in advice

Comment: increase the stroke-width I imagine.

Comment: If I increase the stroke width, all of the areas (the various municipalities) will increase the stroke... while I only need to increase the stroke of the OUTER line...

Comment: break up the drawing into separate paths then.

Comment: I was hoping there was a quicker way...

However, how would you suggest me to separate the paths? Can you suggest me a powerful editor?

Comment: Inkscape can edit SVG files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that each of the areas of the map are their own path - and that you don't already have a path around the outside, then the simplest solution is to:

1. duplicate the map
2. put it at the back
3. give the map paths a thicker stroke

For example, let's start with the following simplified example.

```html
<svg width="400" height="200">
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="200" height="50" fill="linen" stroke="black"/>
  <rect x="250" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="linen" stroke="black"/>
  <rect x="50" y="100" width="150" height="50" fill="linen" stroke="black"/>
  <rect x="200" y="100" width="150" height="50" fill="linen" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

If we take a copy of those elements and give it a thicker stroke, we get:

```html
<svg width="400" height="200">
  <g fill="linen" stroke="black" stroke-width="5">
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="200" height="50"/>
    <rect x="250" y="50" width="100" height="50"/>
    <rect x="50" y="100" width="150" height="50"/>
    <rect x="200" y="100" width="150" height="50"/>
  </g>
  <rect x="50" y="50" width="200" height="50" fill="linen" stroke="black"/>
  <rect x="250" y="50" width="100" height="50" fill="linen" stroke="black"/>
  <rect x="50" y="100" width="150" height="50" fill="linen" stroke="black"/>
  <rect x="200" y="100" width="150" height="50" fill="linen" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

To keep the file as small as possible, we can reuse the paths for both copies of the map:

```html
<svg width="400" height="200">
  <defs>
    <g id="map">
      <rect x="50" y="50" width="200" height="50"/>
      <rect x="250" y="50" width="100" height="50"/>
      <rect x="50" y="100" width="150" height="50"/>
      <rect x="200" y="100" width="150" height="50"/>
    </g>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#map" fill="linen" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
  <use xlink:href="#map" fill="linen" stroke="black"/>
</svg>
```

It's not necessarily the most elegant solution, since all the map elements get drawn twice.  But it is the simplest solution.